# The analysis server shut down unexpectedly. in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

The "analysis server shut down unexpectedly" error in Flutter. I have also tried flutter clean but that did not work.

how to solve this error

Answer (score 0):

You can try to delete the dartServer folder.

On linux / MacOs :
`rm -rf ~/.dartServer`
On windows :
`AppData\Local\.dartServer`

I think you are using VsCode right ?

Comment: no android studio

Comment: I use this cmd but they didn't work

Comment: deleting this folder, reinstall flutter, flutter clean didn't fix the issue ? If you pc have enough storage it's weird.